# Python - how to use optparse callback in order to change an int variable and then use it

Tags: python, parsing, optparse

I want to add options to my python program, such that the user will enter his choice (-c, -l, -lc, etc...) and my optparse will add the choices in prime numbers or something in order to know what the user chose and use it later on in the code.

For instance: userChoice = 1

```
parser.add_option("-c" ........ ??)   # Add the prime number 2 - so userChoice = 2

parser.add_option("-l" ........ ??)   # Add the prime number 3 - so userChoice = 3
```

if the user entered -lc     - userChoice = 6, and so on...

Later on I'll know what the user chose and I'll be able to answer his request, and add more requests easily by adding some more lines with different prime numbers.

Can it be done?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you really have to use `optparse`? I'd suggest using `argparse` but it's available only starting from Python 2.7 (and can be installed as a separate package for earlier versions).

Comment: Another issue is that your interface is not… hm… user-friendly. Can't you just make your user input a number at once? Or maybe a list of nubmers.

Comment: hmmm... I'll think about it again then. Thanks!